# Issue with handling ImportError

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a piece of code that has 2 fallback options in case the preferred solution does not work. The reason for this is that the preferred version of the algorithm depends on OpenSSL being compiled with support for RIPEMD160, which is no longer the case by default as of OpenSSL 3.0, and the second preferred option depends on an additional package that I didn't put in my requirements, and the final fallback option is a slow pure-python implementation.

This is a minimal piece of code to illustrate the issue:

```
import hashlib

assert issubclass(ModuleNotFoundError, ImportError)


def sha256(public_key: bytes) -> bytes:
    return bytes(hashlib.sha256(public_key).digest())


def hash_160(public_key: bytes) -> bytes:
    sha256_hash = sha256(public_key)
    try:
        md = hashlib.new("ripemd160")
        md.update(sha256_hash)
        return md.digest()
    except ValueError:
        from Crypto.Hash import RIPEMD160
        md = RIPEMD160.new()
        md.update(sha256_hash)
        return md.digest()
    except ImportError:
        # from . import ripemd
        # md = ripemd.new(sha256_hash)
        # return md.digest()
        return b""


print(hash_160(b"very test"))
```

The error message is exactly the one I expect, yet the second `except` clause fails to suppress the `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/hashlib.py", line 160, in __hash_new
    return _hashlib.new(name, data, **kwargs)
ValueError: [digital envelope routines] unsupported

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pierre/dev/test_package/./package1/tests/module1.py", line 14, in hash_160
    md = hashlib.new("ripemd160")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/hashlib.py", line 166, in __hash_new
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/hashlib.py", line 123, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type ripemd160

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pierre/dev/test_package/./package1/tests/module1.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(hash_160(b"very test"))
  File "/home/pierre/dev/test_package/./package1/tests/module1.py", line 18, in hash_160
    from Crypto.Hash import RIPEMD160
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I  probably just going to add `pycryptodome` to my requirements and drop the slow python implementation, but the issue still puzzles me.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a dumb error on my part: I should have nested the `try: except` clauses

```
def hash_160(public_key: bytes) -> bytes:
    sha256_hash = sha256(public_key)
    try:
        md = hashlib.new("ripemd160")
        md.update(sha256_hash)
        return md.digest()
    except ValueError:
        try:
            import Cryptodome
            from Cryptodome.Hash import RIPEMD160
            md = RIPEMD160.new()
            md.update(sha256_hash)
            return md.digest()
        except ImportError:
            # from . import ripemd
            # md = ripemd.new(sha256_hash)
            # return md.digest()
            return b""
```